# Retrieve Identity value in entity framework and still able to rollback

Tags: entity-framework-4, transactions, rollback

I want to retrieve the Identity column value after inserting a row in DB using entity framework. So I have to call `context.savechanges()`,  but in case something goes wrong after updating row and retrieving identity column value, I want to to rollback completely.

Is this possible somehow in EF 4.0.?
I know how to retrieve identity column value and by rollback I mean that the inserted row should be deleted.
My identity column is an autogenerated bigint type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `TransactionScope`

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
        // Insert data

        context.SaveChanges();

        // Do something with retrieved Id
    }

    // If something goes wrong and following command is not called
    // transaction will rollback
    scope.Complete(); // Commit
}
```

If you do not call `Complete` transaction will rollback.